# updating apple app store meta data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i am new to iOS and could not find an answer to those questions. Once I submitted an app to the apple app store:

1. can I change the app description while it's in "waiting for review"?
2. can I change the app description while it's in the store and selling, or do I need to submit an update? I am referring specifically to the "Description" field.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes
2. You don't have to submit an update to change the description.

Comment: Will updating meta info affect the position in the review queue?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both your question is yes.

While the app is waiting for review you can edit the app metadata as you need.

Once the app has been approved, you will not be able to add any localization, nor change the app tags, but you will be still allowed to change the rest of the metadata (including the description).

Answer (score 0):

In iTunesConnect As of June 2017, **iOS 11** now supports Promotional Text.

> You can add text without requiring an updated submission.

[image]